# How to link OpenWRT package with libstdcpp

Tags: linker, cross-compiling, openwrt

I have a helloworld package and I can successfully build it with openwrt buildroot for ramips device. In Makefile I have one special include (ulibc) and one special dependency (DEPENDS:=+libc). Package builds and works on device.
Now I need to include gSoap generated code in my helloworld package, but then I have link error:

```
undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
```

What can I do in this case? The next step - adding openssl support and WS Security, could it work on OpenWRT device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

1. Changed compiler in Makefile of my package sources from $(CC) to
   $(CXX) + $(CFLAGS) to $(CXXFLAGS)
2. Included uClibc++.mk before package.mk
3. Add only one dependency: DEPENDS:=+uclibcxx

After this LNK error was fixed. Thanks to @amine.ahd!

Answer (score 0):

You should add gSoap as a seperate package to your Openwrt and then add it as a dependency to your helloworld package (just like what you did for libc)

Comment: But I'll get the same linking problems, when I try to build separate gSoap package - it's sources need the libstdcpp. Isn't it?

Comment: There is already a package for `libstdcpp` in Openwrt, check [here](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=25928) 
Also you can try to use `uClibc++` which is lighter than `libstdcpp`.